# Taskbar buttons dropdown disabled in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Somehow my taskbar buttons dropdown is grayed out and is set to "never combine" in Windows 7. I want to set this to "Combine and Hide labels" but am not able to.

I've found out that the registry key is found under Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrenVersion\Explorer\Advanced TaskbarGlomLevel but changing this and rebooting still does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Turns out to be a domain policy that was set.

Comment: It would have been more helpful if you posted WHERE in domain policy this was set.